# Interpretation of statements such as "between 2 numbers" in questions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

Given that $S\subset \Bbb R$, and

- (i) $0\in S$,
- (ii) if $x\in S$, $2^x+3^x\in S$,
- (iii) if $x^2+x^3\in S$, $x\in S$.

**Asked:** (a) Prove that $S$ is unbounded; (b) Prove that there are at least two numbers that are elements of $S$ **between 0 and 1**.

This question was asked in the list of problems used in the selection process for SUMAC at Stanford in early 2017. My problem here is how to interpret **between 0 and 1**, see question at the end.

**My attempt:**

(a) assume, by contradiction, that the $x>1 \in S$ is the largest number in the set. Notice that $\exists x>1\in S$ as $0\in S$ and by rule (ii) $2\in S$. But as $x\in S$, $y=2^x+3^x\in S$, by rule (ii), but as $x>1$ it holds that $2^x+3^x>x$, contrary to the initial assumption, a contradiction. Therefore $S$ is unbounded.

(b) Need $2$ numbers in $S$ **between 0 and 1**. First is 0, by (i). Second is $1$, as $2\in S$, $2=1^2+1^3$ and by rule (iii), $1\in S$.

**Question:** (a) is my answer acceptable? (b) is it always implicit in a problem statement like that in part (b), "numbers between 0 and 1", the extremes are included? or the statement is ambiguous and should have been expressed in math terms such as $x\in [0,1]$ or $x\in (0,1)$ ?

Comment: A bounded set need not have a largest element. An element $x$ between $0$ and $1$ should satisfy $0<x<1$: otherwise condition (i) would already give the answer.

Comment: I agree that "between $0$ and $1$" is ambiguous.  And, *pace* egreg, condition (i) does not make it obvious what is meant, because it doesn't immediately give **two** elements in the closed interval $[0, 1]$. The question should have said "strictly between $0$ and $1$". Tut, tut!

Comment: I would have answered that since $1\in S$ and there exists $x_1\in (0,1) $ with $x_1^2+x_1^3=1$ and there exists $x_2\in (0,x_1)$ with $x_2^2+x_2^3=x_1,$ so $x_1,x_x\in S$ with $0<x_2<x_1<1,$ and to hell with the ambiguity of "between". I concur with  the comment by Rob Arthan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the comments that between can be ambiguous.  For this question I would read it as strictly between but feel it should be made explicit.  Now that you have shown $1 \in S$ you are almost there.  Note that $x^2+x^3$ is strictly increasing and continuous on $\Bbb R \ge 0$ and equals $0$ when $x=0$ and $2$ when $x=1$.  By the intermediate value theorem, there is some $y \in (0,1)$ such that $y^2+y^3=1$.  You don't have to find it.  Now there is some $z \in (0,1)$ such that $z^2+z^3=y$ and you have found your two.